# SQL query for unique records

Tags: sql, unique

I'm trying to construct a query that gives me the unique records based on a column. This is simplified sample of the data:

```
version        first            last
a              joe              smith
b              jane             smith
c              biff             mcelroy
a              thad             dussledorf
```

I'd like the query to return the unique records based on the `version` (so in this case 1 instance of a, b, and c). For these returned rows, all 3 columns should be represented. So the ideal result would be:

```
version        first            last
a              joe              smith
b              jane             smith
c              biff             mcelroy
```

Comment: Heap tables have no concept of "row order". Does your table have a timestamp or something to use to select the appropriate version "a"?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is this for SQL-Server? Or Postgres? Or Access? Or Firebird? Or SQLite? Or ...?

Comment: For `version a`, what rules do you want to use to select `joe` rather than `thad`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database supports window functions, the best way to do this is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by version order by version) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

This chooses an arbitrary "first" row for each version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would have any bugs/problems:

```
select distinct version,
 (select top 1 [first] from tableName t1 where t1.version = t.version) as [first],
 (select top 1 [last] from tableName t1 where t1.version = t.version) as [last]
from tableName t
```

You could have some sort of " order by xxx" in each subquery.

I'm not sure the 2 subqueries would always bring back the same "top" record...?

But it's not ideal. You're better off having a Record ID or timestamp or something to work with, then you would use a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothered about which unique versions should be returned among multiple ones, you can simply use group by:

```
select version, first_name, last_name from table name group by version;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on the database. If you are using Oracle (pl/sql) then you can use the Rank over function:

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT version, first, last RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY version ORDER BY first) RANK FROM SomeTable) WHERE RANK = 1;

Copy and pasting this query might not work. So please read http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rank.php to get an idea of what needs to be done.